# Exception thrown while executing UI block : [RCTView updateContentSizeIfNeeded]: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: react-native, expo, react-native-flatlist

I am working on a expo app and want to display a tutorial on top on the map on the first connexion, like this :

[image]
[image]

The problem is that I have this error :

[image]

I think that it comes from the FlatList inside my code because it works without the flatlist. Anyway, here is my code :

```html
<MapView
            style={styles.map}
            loadingEnabled={true}
            showsUserLocation={true}
            initialRegion={{
              latitude: location.coords.latitude,
              longitude: location.coords.longitude,
              latitudeDelta: 0.0922,
              longitudeDelta: 0.0421,
            }}
          >
            <View style={styles.centeredView}>
              <View style={styles.innerModal}>
                <FlatList
                  data={tutorialData}
                  style={styles.flatlist}
                  horizontal
                  pagingEnabled
                  renderItem={({ item }) => <TutorialItem item={item} />}
                />
              </View>
            </View>
 </MapView>

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  map: {
    height: height,
    position: "relative",
    zIndex: 1,
  },
  centeredView: {
    alignItems: "center",
  },
  innerModal: {
    width: windowWidth / 1.3,
    height: height / 5,
    alignSelf: "center",
    marginTop: height / 5,
    borderRadius: 20,
    backgroundColor: "lightgrey",
    borderColor: "white",
    borderWidth: 2,
    padding: "5%",
  },
  flatlist: {
    height: "100%",
    width: "100%",
  }
})
```

And my TutorialItem component :

```html
const TutorialItem = ({ item }) => {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <Text>{item.title}</Text>
      <Text>{item.text}</Text>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    height: "100%",
    zIndex: 4,
    maxWidth: windowWidth / 1.5,
  },
});
```